# Website take more seconds to load - Django with Nginx GCE VM

Tags: django, nginx, gcloud

Am using Django 1.7  , Nginx and Google compute Engine virtual server.

But when I load my page it takes more time to load.

Even I have optimized the query. I have checked the query it takes only less than a second. But the entire page take more time even it has parallel processing.

[image]

In the above picture the firt bit take around 7 seconds to complete.
the detail of the above picture is given below.

[image]

Could you Please tell how to reduce the waiting time.

Is there any problem with nginx or gcloud?.

Even in the server If I put print by time difference before rendering it take only a second to execute it. But I dont know why it takes more time to load a page completely.

In example.com which is inside /etc/nginx/site-enabled and site-available

```
upstream test {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        keepalive 500;
}


server {

    listen   80;
    server_name myservername.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;


    error_page 502 =200 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
        root /path/to/static/offline/files;
        try_files $uri /index.html =503;
    }
   location /static/ {

       alias  /home/sim/5vs/staticfiles/;

    }

    location /media/ {
       alias  /home/sim/5vs/myproject/myproject/site_media/media/;
       expires 30d;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                 proxy_pass http://test;
                 break;
        }

    }
}
```

in nginx.conf file has

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My django view file is

```
@login_required
def dash_view(request):
    t1 = datetime.now()
    dashbardTempCont = {}
    trLists =""
    if 'label_id' in request.session:
        if(request.session['label_id']!=""):
            arId = request.session['label_id']
            alLists = Al.objects.filter(user_id=arId).count()
            dashbardTempCont['alCount'] = alLists
            trLists = Tr.objects.filter(ar_id_id=arId).filter(~Q(al_id=None)).exclude(deleted_status=1).values_list('irc','ar_name','file')
    else:
        profileDetails = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
        if(str(profileDetails.user_type)=='A'):
            arId = request.session['_auth_user_id']
            alLists = Al.objects.filter(user_id=arId).count()
            dashbardTempCont['alCount'] = alLists
            trLists = Tracks.objects.filter(ar_id_id=arId).filter(~Q(al_id=None)).exclude(deleted_status=1).values_list('isrc','ar_name','file')
        elif(str(profileDetails.user_type)=='M'):
            userIdArr = []
            arDetails =  Profile.objects.filter(label_id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
            if(arDetails):
                for arDetail in arDetails:
                    userIdArr.append(arDetail.user_id)
                trLists = Tracks.objects.filter(ar_id__in=userIdArr).filter(~Q(al_id=None)).exclude(deleted_status=1).values_list('isrc','ar_name','file')

    videoCnt = 0
    trackCnt = 0
    isrc = []
    arName = []
    for trackList in trLists:
        isrc.append(trackList[0])        
        arName.append(trackList[1])
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(trackList[2])
        videoExtensionArr = ['.mp4','.png']
        if extension in videoExtensionArr:            
            videoCnt = videoCnt +1
        else:
            trackCnt = trackCnt +1
    dashbardTempCont['videoCnt'] = videoCnt
    dashbardTempCont['trackCnt'] = trackCnt
    """
    filter using ar_name for extra isrc protection. 
    """
    rtDetails = Rev_Rt.objects.filter(isrc__in=isrc).filter(ar_name__in=arName).values_list('store_name','rv');
    spotifyDetails = ""
    youtubeDetails = ""
    rdioDetails = ""
    googleDetails = ""

    storeDetails = Store.objects.values_list('name')

    for storeDetail in storeDetails:
        if 'spotify' in storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8').lower():
            spotifyDetails = rtDetails.filter(store_name=storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8'))
        elif 'youtube' in storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8').lower():
            youtubeDetails = rtDetails.filter(store_name=storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8'))
        elif 'rdio' in storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8').lower():
            rdioDetails = rtDetails.filter(store_name=storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8'))
        elif 'google play' in storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8').lower():
            googleDetails = rtDetails.filter(store_name=storeDetail[0].encode('utf-8'))
    revenueArr = []
    spRevenueArr = []
    yRevenueArr = []
    rdRevenueArr = []
    gRevenueArr = []
    for rtDetail in rtDetails:
        if rtDetail[1]:
            revenueArr.append(rtDetail[1])
    for spDetail in spotifyDetails:
        if spDetail[1]:
            spRevenueArr.append(spDetail[1])
    for yDetail in yDetails:
        if yoDetail[1]:
            yRevenueArr.append(yDetail[1])
    for rdDetail in rdDetails:
        if rdDetail[1]:
            rdRevenueArr.append(rdDetail[1])
    for gDetail in gDetails:
        if gDetail[1]:
            gRevenueArr.append(gDetail[1])
    dashbardTempCont['totRevenue']=round(sum(revenueArr),2)
    dashbardTempCont['sptotRevenue']=round(sum(sRevenueArr),2)
    dashbardTempCont['ytotRevenue']=round(sum(yRevenueArr),2)
    dashbardTempCont['rdtotRevenue']=round(sum(rdRevenueArr),2)
    dashbardTempCont['gtotRevenue']=round(sum(gRevenueArr),2)       
    t2 = datetime.now()
    t1 = datetime.now()
    returndata = render_to_response('tr/dash.html',dashbardTempCont,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    t3 = datetime.now()
    print (t3-t2).seconds,'seconds'
    return returndata
```

While running the above view file it prints less than 2 seconds to complete the progress while rendering this to template take more time I think.

my sample template file sample is ,

```
            <div class="upload-more-tracks clearfix text-center">
                <div class="container">
                {% if labelArLists.count > 5 %}
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="np-track edit-prev prevItems pull-left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> <strong>Previous</strong></a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if request.session.label_artist_id %}   
                    <a href="{% url 'track_management:label_view'  %}"><span class="uploadingTracksCount">Return to your view</span></a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if labelArtistLists.count > 5 %}  
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="np-track edit-next nextItems pull-right"><strong>Next</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                {% endif %}    
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="dash-bottom">

                    {% if userType == "L" and labelArtist.id == "" %}
                        <p>Choose artist to upload tracks </p>
                    {% else %}
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li>Albums <span>{{ alCount }}</span></li>
                        <li>Tracks <span>{{ trCnt }}</span></li>
                        <li>Videos <span>{{ videoCnt }}</span></li>
                         </ul>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
                    <script>
                        var doughnutData = [
                            {
                                value: {{ sptotRevenue }},
                                color:"#81b900"
                            },
                            {
                               // value : {{ gRevenue }},
                                value : {{ gRevenue }},
                                color : "#fc8521"
                            },
                            {
                                value : {{ ytRevenue }},
                                color : "#e12a27"
                            },
                            {
                                value : {{ rdRevenue  }},
                                color : "#0086cd"
                            }

                        ];

                        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
                    </script>
```

...
...

I have added the django toolbar. the screenshot is attached below.

[image]

Comment: you should return a blank html file without any context data at the end of your View and see how fast it loads. Additionally, install Django Debug Toolbar and it will tell you how long your queries take, response time, time spent in DOM loading, etc. https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/

Comment: @MarkGalloway I have tested as you said , the full html file take 15seconds to load and an empty file takes 5 seconds to load.

Comment: And I have added the django toolbar. I have attached the screen shot of that.

Comment: So 10 seconds is being lost to rendering? You variables are hard to read, it is possible you are making some queries by accident in the template, which is very slow. Perhaps the Django Debug Toolbar will be able to tell you if there are any extra queries you weren't expecting.

Comment: @MarkGalloway There is no extra queries, The variable are changed in my machine. So your conclusion is we dont do any operations in the template file?

Comment: how long does it take to load a page from `/var/root/html` (without django et al)? Do you have debug set to true in django? A lot of your load time there seems to be collecting static files too, does it take as long to load on the second time you load the page?

Comment: @Sayse For second time it takes only 4 or 5 seconds to load but For First time only It takes 15 to 20 seconds.

Comment: In the above case it is 10+ seconds taken to load your static content (since it caches it for subsequent requests), I presume you have ran `collectstatic`?

Comment: @Sayse Yes, I do run collectstatic if I change any static files.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll fully be able to help pinpoint the exact issues here at the minute but definitely look into static files as this seems to be where most of the time is spent. Django's documentation has advice on [deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: Ok, I have moved the staticfiles directory to other location which is pointing from other server. but loading time is 9seconds. and Waiting time is 6seconds.

Answer (score 1):

How many objects are you 'processing' in the template? If it is any more than a dozen or so, you can start to see noticeable delays (depending on the operation). The template snippit you provided appears to be the inside of a for loop within the template, and based upon your queries, you have a pretty substantial DB presence. The fact that your view takes more than 2 seconds also indicates a ton of processing.

Template processing is the slowest part of Django. If you are dealing with a large iteration within a template, you should be filtering the data as much as possible within the view, either within the ORM (preferable usually) or in Python. If you are tossing/not displaying elements in your template, be sure to remove those ahead of time from your context so that your template doesn't waste time. Also consider pagination, humans can't take in that much data at once.

Or maybe you are displaying a single album with 10 tracks, in which case I would look at figuring out which specific lines in your template are being problematic, and address accordingly. Use a simple template tag in strategic places to print out time stamps somewhere.

Another problem I've seen is wait time based on coercion of ORM data to models in complicated and far reaching queries, but your problem (mainly) appears to be template related.

I doubt your static files are to blame. Your original profiling graph shows that the static files aren't retrieved until after the delay of receiving the initial HTML page (which is obviously how the web works, but I'm simply exonerating your static files based on the data provided).

Comment: So I have to ignore the template processing in view itself and In my case which is best ORM or raw_sql. Or I need to change my query in orm. And I didn't understand about the staticfile section.

Comment: And I have checked the template processing also takes a seconds only. Please see my view file now the time consuming of returndata only takes around a second.

Comment: As far as the static files go, the 'delay' that you are seeing when pulling down the static files is expected. When a browser makes a request, the first thing sent back is the initial HTML page (generated by your template). Once that HTML file is sent by the server, the browser parses the HTML and process to retrieve all of the external resources needed to properly display the HTML page, such as images, CSS files, etc. Notice how all of your other files start as soon as the initial file is finished retrieving at the top, since the locations of those files are unknown until that moment.

Comment: I would recommend profiling the template itself before looking at the view, since you've determined the view only takes ~2 seconds to run. Create a quick simple template tag that prints a timestamp and put it in the template at various points to see what portion of the template is taking the longest, similar to what you did in the view above.

Comment: Can you add a t3 = datetime.now() and do another delta against T1 on the line above your final return statement? I bet that would show the delay you are seeing. It would also validate that the template rendering is the problem

Comment: As you said, I have added the new var t3 you can see the changes in view file. But prints only 0 seconds. please help me on this